# Between with Variables for prior months start and stop

Tags: oracle

I use the following WHERE with sysdate to get a between range.

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(mopstart, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 21:00:00' AND TO_CHAR(sysdate+1,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' 20:59:59'
```

My question is, how do I create a BETWEEN with variables for the date to return the prior months start and end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually not use BETWEEN for this. As in real life you would not say "the time from beginning of last month till the end of last month", but just "last month", so you would do in SQL.

Knowing that a month is actually the year and the month:

```
where extract(year from mopstart) = extract(year from sysdate) 
and extract(month from mopstart) = extract(month from sysdate) - 1
```

Or:

```
where to_char(mopstart,'yyyymm') = to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'yyyymm')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, that would be:

```
where ... between trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MON') and trunc(sysdate, 'MON') - 1
```

One more thing: don't use `TO_CHAR` to compare dates, just use dates and intervals.